# Android: Cover underlying elevated views, and making a flat button

Tags: android, layout, material-design

Sorry for the elementary question but I can't find the solution:

When covering a button with a layout without elevation, it emerges over the layout because a button has a depth (negative depth, it points at the viewer).

So, if you have a

```
<FrameLayout... >
     <Button.../>
     <FrameLayout 
        id="@+id/fragmentsContainerOrAnything"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#C00F"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        >          
     </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The button would show through the `FrameLayout`.... In this case, literally "out of the blue" because the button has depth and so it emerges over the layout, even though the layout is placed "upon" the button.

The question is:

1. How do I make the `FrameLayout` cover the underlying `Button` without fiddling with its elevation.
2. How do I make the button flat? Of course I can just set it back to the origins and call it "TextView". But is there a nicer way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add your button inside FrameLayout

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#C00F"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```